# How to add dynamic key in Formik initial Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am using useFormik hook to build form and validate input fields. I want am validating 5 input fields just fine but i have to validate another 15 inputs, which are mapped through two arrays and their names are all different. Here is my initialValues object

```
const LAUNDRY_FORM_INITIAL_VALUES: ILaundryFormInitialValues = {
  name: "",
  logo: "",
  address: "",
  phone: "",
  startTime: moment(new Date()).set({ hour: 8, minute: 0 }).toDate(),
  endTime: moment(new Date()).set({ hour: 22, minute: 0 }).toDate(),
  is24: false,
  boxes: null,
  district: null
}
```

each key here represents value and name of each input. **I wanna add one dynamic key here that will be key of all 15 inputs**. Here is the code of my input element

```
{bodyTypes.map(( bodyType: ICarBodyType, j: number ) => (
                <Flex key={bodyType.id} mt={"20px"} flexDirection={"column"} >
                  <Input
                    name={`body${bodyType.id}-wash${washType.id}`}
                    value={serviceData[`body${bodyType.id}-wash${washType.id}`]?.price || ""}
                  />
                </Flex>
              ))}
```

You see that their `name` and `value` attributes are not some static string like this input i have validated without any problem:

```
<Input
            id="laundry-phone"
            name="phone"
            label={T("laundry.form.phone_label")}
            value={values.phone}
            type="number"
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            styles={{ width: "100%", height: "60px" }}
            error={Boolean(errors.phone && touched.phone)}
            errorMessage={errors.phone}
          />
```